# Measure performance of query when using subqueries or functions

Tags: mysql, subquery

I use EXPLAIN to measure performance of query. It works fine. But it does not take into consideration subqueries or fucntions in queries. How can i check if function is causing problem in query.

Comment: It does, check the rows where it says "(table) <derivedX>"